# Can we create a project for oracle database deployment similar to visual studio SSDT project

Tags: database, oracle, deployment

I need a way to deploy the oracle database in a single click, something similar to SSDT projects.

Comment: what is your question? In a single script you can do anything you can dream for ...

Comment: Does it have to be from Visual Studio? Do you need to version control your changes? More background would be helpful.

Comment: yes, I need it in VS 2013 for Oracle Database deployment. It should have version control.

Answer (score 1):

Red Gate (where I work) has [a set of deployment tools for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/), including version control, but they are not tightly integrated in Visual Studio. They were designed to be standalone as unlike for SQL Server, there are a handful of different IDEs in the Oracle scene, including Toad, SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer.

The predecessor of SSDT had Oracle support via a Quest Extension, but this was discontinued with the release of SSDT.